# How to convert .exe file to windows setup wizard

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, ttk

I was creating an app through Tkinter. And after making I converted into .exe file using pyinstaller. It is good but I want to make it more professional. Like when we download any application from internet and open it it opens a setup wizard with license agreements and where to put all the files. I do not want to share my exe file but want to share my setup file. So, that when they click it will show license agreements, the path to save, and a few more like a real setup wizard.

Please help me how can I create that in Tkinter python?

Comment: Actually there is a better installer, NSIS looks unprofessional. I would recommend Inno setup

Comment: oh, which? Will I get setup wizard in that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[NSIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) is one of the many options available but i would recommend [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) because it is actually a simple and powerfull setup wizard, I have been using NSIS and found out about Inno Setup recently and have been using it since then. It has the License agreement parts and all that we are looking to add into.

Hope this is what you want. Do let me know if any errors.

[Video example on making a setup wizard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-p-4titD2Y)

**This is not sponsored.**

Answer (score 2):

A popular and simple option is using NSIS, as explained [here](https://youtu.be/UZX5kH72Yx4?t=328).

Comment: In NSIS, we cannot put a license agreement and etc easily

Comment: oh ok then I will try inno setup

Comment: First, to answer OP's question about adding a license agreement, [here's a post about doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310048/adding-license-information-to-nsis-installer). @CoolCloud Well, NSIS is more powerful than it looks, it actually has a full scripting language to it, it can handle complex installation tasks and it has lots of available plug-ins and scripts. You can also fully customize the design of installation wizards made with NSIS.

Comment: @pitamer Its not _"easy"_, while it is, with Inno setup (is the reason why i like it.)

Comment: I tried to install NSIS. And my browser told it is blocked and it acted like NSIS is virus. Is it outdated software? So, I think inno setup will be good option